# Using a Double for a duration in an Android animation

Tags: android, kotlin, double, android-animation, long-integer

I have run into a big issue regarding AlphaAnimation. I am trying to achieve a **very precise** alpha animation. Think musical cadence / musical metronome.

AlphaAnimation seems to only accept a `Long` value for the duration argument. I need to be able to accept a `Double` to achieve the intended precision.

If I convert Double to Long, I lose the decimal, which ruins the precision.

**Here's my progress:**

```
var metronome = 0.46511627906976744
var doubleForAnimation = (metronome * 1000) // Prints out: 465.1162790697674 - which is precise!

val alphaAnimation = AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f)
alphaAnimation.duration = doubleForAnimation.roundToLong() // Prints out: 465 which is NOT precise!!
alphaAnimation.repeatCount = -1
alphaAnimation.repeatMode = Animation.ABSOLUTE
metronomeView.startAnimation(alphaAnimation)
```

**Is there any possible way to use doubleForAnimation for duration in an Android alpha animation?**

This may sound trivial, but the precision here is an *absolute must*.

Comment: Duration is presented in milliseconds, and most devices will only render at 60hz which means ~14ms frame time. So your 465ms animation will render over 33 frames anyway. Decimal precision won't matter in that case.

Comment: Given that the duration field is in milliseconds, the app would be responsible for missed/dropped frames/synchronization, especially since most screens are limited to 60 fps with a few at higher refresh rates. If you are having issues, you may want to render to OpenGL as a game engine would.